# Al listar los objetos del arreglo me mestra el mismo objeto 2 veces en javascript

Tags: javascript, array, validación

Buenas tengo este código para que un usuario entre un nombre de película y un rating. Y como resultado se muestre las películas con rating > 7.

Lo que me sucede es que ingreso 2 elementos -> 1) Tarzan  y 8 2) La sirena y 9
Y al final siempre me lista "la sirena y 9".

Ademas valido que el rating sea numérico.
Cuando el usuario da click en cancelar termina de ingresar elementos.

En un caso de inicializar la variable (*) , si me muestra los dos registros bien.

Alguno me puede explicar el porque??, soy nueva en javascript , así que cualquier ayuda os lo agradezco.

```
let myArrayMovies = [];
let myObjectMovie = {};
let rankingTmp;


while(1){
    let myNameMovie = prompt("Nombre de la peli","Hola");
   
    if ( myNameMovie == null)
        break;

    let rankingTmp = prompt("Ranking de la peli[0-9]",1);
    
    if ( rankingTmp == null)
        break;

    let myRankingMovie = Number(rankingTmp);
        
       
    let isNumber =  Number.isNaN(myRankingMovie);
    
    if (myNameMovie && !isNumber){
        //myObjectMovie = {}; (*) --> Por que ???
        myObjectMovie.name =  myNameMovie;
        myObjectMovie.ranking = myRankingMovie;

        myArrayMovies.push(myObjectMovie);
     }
    else
        break;
}

for (let e of myArrayMovies){
        if(e.ranking >= 7){
            console.log(e.ranking);
            console.log(e.name);
        }
}
```

Comment: Te fijas en el comentario `//myObjectMovie = {}; (*) --> Por que ???` es para no asignar valores al objeto que pusheaste en el buble anterior. Pero esa no es la manera. Simplemente pushea un objeto literal `{name: myNameMovie, ranking: myRankingMovie}`

Answer (score 1):

Con **let myObjectMovie = {};** declaras un objeto, osea reservas un lugar en la memoria para guardarlo.
En la primer iteración haces:

```
myObjectMovie.name =  myNameMovie;
myObjectMovie.ranking = myRankingMovie;
```

Osea instancias el objeto, luego con:

```
myArrayMovies.push( myObjectMovie );
```

agregas el objeto instanciado a tu `array`, osea el `array` va a tener un puntero a la locación en memoria del objeto.
En la segunda iteración, repites el proceso, pero en vez de instanciar el objeto, lo estás modificando (ya estaba instanciado) y lo agregas al `array`, pero el puntero que agregaste antes, apunta al mismo lugar de la memoria, que ahora fue modificada, por lo que te muestra el valor repetido, tienes dos punteros al mismo lugar de la memoria, si en cambio, haces lo que marcas con **(*)**, estás instanciando un nuevo objeto (si, aunque tenga el mismo nombre), por lo que muestra el resultado que esperas.
Haciendo una repasada a tu código...

```
let rankingTmp;    
while( 1 ) {
    let myNameMovie = prompt( "Nombre de la peli","Hola" );       
    if( myNameMovie == null )         break;

    let rankingTmp = prompt( "Ranking de la peli[0-9]", 1 );
```

como puedes ver, re-declaras **rankingTmp**, que deja sin sentido la primer declaración (la puedes quitar).
También podemos declarar en el lugar de uso a **myObjectMovie**.

```
if (myNameMovie && !isNumber){
    let myObjectMovie = {}; 
    myObjectMovie.name =  myNameMovie;
    myObjectMovie.ranking = myRankingMovie;
```

y también podemos ahorrar un paso creando el objeto en la propia instanciación del array:

```
myArrayMovies.push( { name: myNameMovie, ranking: myRankingMovie } );
```

Espero haber aclarado tu duda.

Comment: Me ha quedado claro muchas gracias por vuestra ayuda